# Destroying MainActivity gives me NullPointerException on HoneyComb

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-cursoradapter, android-loadermanager

Whenever the user quits my app (MainActivity) using honeycomb I'm getting the following error:

```
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.maddogs.mymoney/com.maddogs.mymoney.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3655)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3673)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at com.maddogs.mymoney.adapters.PeopleCursorAdapter.getItemId(PeopleCursorAdapter.java:69)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onSaveInstanceState(AbsListView.java:885)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.widget.ListView.onSaveInstanceState(ListView.java:3625)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.widget.AdapterView.access$100(AdapterView.java:42)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AdapterView.java:800)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:43)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(BaseAdapter.java:54)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.swapCursor(CursorAdapter.java:352)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.changeCursor(CursorAdapter.java:315)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at com.maddogs.mymoney.MainActivity.onLoaderReset(MainActivity.java:311)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.destroy(LoaderManager.java:339)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.doDestroy(LoaderManager.java:776)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:337)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3642)
06-12 02:30:42.612: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  ... 11 more
```

I can't understand why this happens on Honeycomb but not on later versions (I tested using android 4.2 on my mobile S3).

My code:

PeopleCursorAdapter:

```
package com.maddogs.mymoney.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.maddogs.mymoney.R;
import com.maddogs.mymoney.provider.MyMoneyContract.Users;
import com.maddogs.mymoney.utils.Utils;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class PeopleCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public PeopleCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);

        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View arg0, Context arg1, Cursor arg2) {
        // String id =
        // arg2.getString(arg2.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Users.USER_ID));

        String name = arg2.getString(arg2
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(Users.USER_NAME));

        // String email = arg2.getString(arg2
        // .getColumnIndexOrThrow(Users.USER_EMAIL));

        // String profilePic = arg2.getString(arg2
        // .getColumnIndexOrThrow(Users.USER_PROFILEPIC));

        Double value = arg2.getDouble(arg2
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(Users.USER_BALANCE));

        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) arg0.findViewById(R.id.peopleName);
        nameTextView.setText(name);

        TextView valueTextView = (TextView) arg0
                .findViewById(R.id.peopleDebitsBalance);
        if (value >= 0.00)
            valueTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
        else
            valueTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        valueTextView.setText(Utils.convertCurrency(arg1, value));

        ImageView profilePicImageView = (ImageView) arg0
                .findViewById(R.id.peopleProfilePicture);

        Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.rata_logo)
                .into(profilePicImageView);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        Cursor c = getCursor();
        if (c.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return Long.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Users._ID)));
        } else
            return -1;
    }

    public String getPersonName(int position) {
        Cursor c = getCursor();
        if (c.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Users.USER_NAME));
        } else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_people, arg2, false);
    }

}
```

MainActivity (some snippets):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarListActivity implements
        OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener, LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        adapter = new PeopleCursorAdapter(this, null, 0);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
...
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, UsersListView.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { Users.USER_BALANCE, Users.USER_NAME,
                        Users.USER_ID, Users._ID }, null, null, null);

        return loader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
        this.adapter.changeCursor(arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        this.adapter.changeCursor(null);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: what is line 69 if the PeopleCursorAdapter?

Comment: `if (c.moveToPosition(position)) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't want to but solved doing this:

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        Cursor c = getCursor();
        if (c == null)
            return -1;
        if (c.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return Long.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Users._ID)));
        } else
            return -1;
    }

    public String getPersonName(int position) {
        Cursor c = getCursor();
        if (c == null)
            return null;
        if (c.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Users.USER_NAME));
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onDestroy you need to check if adapter is not null and remove the underlying cursor of your adapter

**example:**

```
 protected void onDestroy() {
   if( adapter != null ) { 
      adapter.changeCursor( null ); 
      adapter = null;
    }
   super.onDestroy();

 }
```

checker

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    if(this.adapter != null)
        this.adapter.changeCursor(arg1);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    if(this.adapter != null)
       this.adapter.changeCursor(null);
}
```

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari does it only occurs upon quitting the app?

Comment: Yes, on honeycomb only (For the older versions, was the only one that I tested. On newer versions (4.2) it doesn't happen at all!)

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari try to set the adapter to null editted. before ondestroy.

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari add a checker on your onLoadFinished i am guessing that it is still accessing your adapter when you are destroying it

Comment: Wouldn't be better to add a checker before `if (c.moveToPosition(position)) {` to check for the cursor ?

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari it will be a good idea to check for null.. I am really  sure that you are accessing the cursor upon destroying it.

Comment: Thanks, I added a null check on the adapter itself before every cursor use and it works. Thanks for all the help

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari anytime champ. :))